# Having trouble with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

So I am trying to run my test which is suppose to pass now but I keep getting an error

```
1) Sign in flow successful redirects to the topics index
     Failure/Error: visit('/topics')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #
<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SignInFlow::Successful:0x007fd91e36f8e0>
     # ./spec/models/sign_in_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my sign_in_spec.rb file

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Sign in flow" do 

  include TestFactories

  describe "successful" do 
    it "redirects to the topics index" do 
      user = authenticated_user
      visit root_path
    end
  end
end
```

And my rails_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

I am not sure but I don't think I need to create a route for root_path do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't `/` -- it's `visit` as your error shows. That method doesn't exist in this spec file. That's a Capybara method, and Capybara is for feature specs.

It looks like the problem is that you're trying to run a "features" spec in a model spec file. Capybara, which creates the domain specific language you're using, sets it to be available only in certain spec folders. If you move the spec into the `spec/features` folder, that may fix it.